# How do i keep the ratios consistent when using SVG as background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have build a website where all my sizes are vw units. So i have a 320px standard and 3.125vw equals 10 pixels at that resolution.

My issue surfaces when the viewport scales. The stars in star ratings are made up of svgs and the scaling seems inconsisten. Why does this happen exactly? The svg is 11x10px as base dimension. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="rating">
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="full rating-5-0"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .recommended-products .product-list .item > .rating {
        margin-left: 25vw;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 4.6875vw;

        width: 17.1875vw;
        height: 3.125vw;
    }

    .recommended-products .product-list .item .rating > .empty {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        background-image: url("resources/mobile-app/resources/icon_Star_None.svg");
        background-size: contain;
    }

    .recommended-products .product-list .item .rating > .full {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;

        background-image: url("resources/mobile-app/resources/icon_Star_Full.svg");
        background-size: contain;

    }

    /* ---- Rating values ---- 0.5 increments */

    .recommended-products .product-list .item .rating > .full.rating-5-0 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .recommended-products .product-list .item .rating > .full.rating-4-5 {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .recommended-products .product-list .item .rating > .full.rating-4-0 {
        width: 80%;
    }
```

[full star](http://svgur.com/s/30i)

[empty star](http://svgur.com/s/302)

Comment: excuse that, i added them

Comment: @RobertLongson anything new?